# Fixed point approximation of 2^x, with input range of s5.26

Tags: fixed-point, approximation

How can I implement 2^x fixed-point arithmetic s5.26 and input values is in range [-31.9, 31.9] using the minimax polynomial approximation for exp2()
How to generate the polynomial using Sollya Tool mentioned in the following link
[Power of 2 approximation in fixed point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550388/power-of-2-approximation-in-fixed-point/36662014)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since fixed-point arithmetic generally does not include an "infinity" encoding representing overflowed results, any implementation of `exp2()` for an `s5.26` format will be limited to inputs in the interval (-32, 5), resulting in outputs in [0, 32).

The computation of transcendental functions typically consist of argument reduction, core approximation, final result construction. In the case of `exp2(a)`, a reasonable argument reduction scheme is to split `a` into integer part `i` and fractional part `f`, such that `a == i + f`, with `f` in [-0.5, 0.5]. One then computes `exp2(f)`, and scales the result by 2<sup>`i`</sup>, which corresponds to shifts in fixed-point arithmetic: `exp2(a) = exp2(f) * exp2(i)`.

The common design choices for the computation of `exp2(f)` are interpolation in tabulated values of `exp2()`, or polynomial approximation. Since we need 31 result bits for the largest arguments, accurate interpolation would probably want to use quadratic interpolation to keep the table size reasonable. Since many modern processors (including ones used in embedded systems) provide a fast integer multiplier, I will focus here on approximation by polynomial. For this, we want a polynomial with minimax properties, that is, one that minimizes the maximum error compared to the reference.

Both commercial and free tools offer built-in capabilities to generate minimax approximations, e.g. Mathematica's `MiniMaxApproximation` command, Maple's `minimax` command, and Sollya's `fpminimax` command. One might also chose to build one's own infrastructure based on the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm), which is the approach I have used. As opposed to floating-point arithmetic which typically uses to-nearest-or-even rounding, fixed-point  arithmetic is usually restricted to truncation of intermediate results. This adds additional error during expression evaluation. As a consequence, it is usually a good idea to try a heuristic-based search for small adjustments to the coefficients of the generated approximation to partially balance those accumulating one-sided errors.

Because we need up to 31 bits in the result, and because coefficients in core approximations are typically less than unity in magnitude, we cannot use the native fixed-point precision, here `s5.26`, for polynomial evaluation. Instead, we want to scale up the operands in intermediate computation to fully use the available range of 32-bit integers, by dynamically adjusting the fixed-point format we are working in. For reasons of efficiency, it seems advisable to arrange the computation such that multiplications use re-normalization right shifts by 32 bits. This will often allow the elimination of explicit shifts on 32-bit processors.

Since intermediate computation uses signed data, right shifts of signed, negative operands will occur. We want those right shifts to map to arithmetic right shift instructions, something the C standard does **not** guarantee. But on most commonly used platforms, C compilers do what is desirable for us. Otherwise, it may be necessary to resort to intrinsics or inline assembly. I developed the code below with the Microsoft compiler on an x64 platform.

In the evaluation of the polynomial approximation for `exp2(f)` the original floating-point coefficients, the dynamic scaling, and the heuristic adjustments are all clearly visible. The code below does not quite achieve full accuracy for large arguments. The biggest absolute error is 1.10233e-7, for the argument of `0x12de9c5b` = 4.71739332: `fixed_exp2()` returns `0x693ab6a3` while the accurate result would be `0x693ab69c`. Presumably full accuracy could be achieved by increasing the degree of the polynomial core approximation by one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

/* on 32-bit architectures, there is often an instruction/intrinsic for this */
int32_t mulhi (int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
    return (int32_t)(((int64_t)a * (int64_t)b) >> 32);
}

/* compute exp2(a) in s5.26 fixed-point arithmetic */
int32_t fixed_exp2 (int32_t a)
{
    int32_t i, f, r, s;
    /* split a = i + f, such that f in [-0.5, 0.5] */
    i = (a + 0x2000000) & ~0x3ffffff; // 0.5
    f = a - i;   
    s = ((5 << 26) - i) >> 26;
    f = f << 5; /* scale up for maximum accuracy in intermediate computation */
    /* approximate exp2(f)-1 for f in [-0.5, 0.5] */
    r =                (int32_t)(1.53303146e-4 * (1LL << 36) + 996);
    r = mulhi (r, f) + (int32_t)(1.33887795e-3 * (1LL << 35) +  99);
    r = mulhi (r, f) + (int32_t)(9.61833261e-3 * (1LL << 34) + 121);
    r = mulhi (r, f) + (int32_t)(5.55036329e-2 * (1LL << 33) +  51);
    r = mulhi (r, f) + (int32_t)(2.40226507e-1 * (1LL << 32) +   8);
    r = mulhi (r, f) + (int32_t)(6.93147182e-1 * (1LL << 31) +   5);
    r = mulhi (r, f);
    /* add 1, scale based on integral portion of argument, round the result */
    r = ((((uint32_t)r * 2) + (uint32_t)(1.0*(1LL << 31)) + ((1U << s) / 2) + 1) >> s);
    /* when argument < -26.5, result underflows to zero */
    if (a < -0x6a000000) r = 0;
    return r;
}

/* convert from s5.26 fixed point to double-precision floating point */
double fixed_to_float (int32_t a)
{
    return a / 67108864.0;
}

int main (void)
{
    double a, res, ref, err, maxerr = 0.0;
    int32_t x, start, end;

    start = -0x7fffffff; // -31.999999985
    end =    0x14000000; //   5.000000000
    printf ("testing fixed_exp2 with inputs in [%.9f, %.9f)\n",  
            fixed_to_float (start), fixed_to_float (end));

    for (x = start; x < end; x++) {
        a = fixed_to_float (x);
        ref = exp2 (a);
        res = fixed_to_float (fixed_exp2 (x));
        err = fabs (res - ref);
        if (err > maxerr) {
            maxerr = err;
        }
    }
    printf ("max. abs. err = %g\n", maxerr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A table-based alternative would trade-off table storage for a reduction in the amount of computation that is performed. Depending on the size of the L1 data cache, this may or may not increase performance. One possible approach is to tabulate 2<sup>f</sup>-1 for `f` in [0, 1). The split the function argument into an integer `i` and a fraction `f`, such that `f` in [0, 1). In order to keep the table reasonably small, use quadratic interpolation, with the coefficients of the polynomial computed on the fly from three consecutive table entries. The result is slightly adjusted by a heuristically determined offset to somewhat compensate for the truncating nature of fixed-point arithmetic.

The table is indexed by leading bits of the fraction `f`. Using seven bits for the index (resulting in a table of 128+2 entries), accuracy is slightly worse than with the previous minimax polynomial approximation. Maximum absolute error is 1.74935e-7. It occurs for an argument of `0x11580000` = 4.33593750, where `fixed_exp2()` returns `0x50c7d771`, whereas the accurate result would be `0x50c7d765`.

```c
/* For i in [0,129]: (exp2 (i/128.0) - 1.0) * (1 << 31) */
static const uint32_t expTab [130] =
{
    0x00000000, 0x00b1ed50, 0x0164d1f4, 0x0218af43,
    0x02cd8699, 0x0383594f, 0x043a28c4, 0x04f1f656,
    0x05aac368, 0x0664915c, 0x071f6197, 0x07db3580,
    0x08980e81, 0x0955ee03, 0x0a14d575, 0x0ad4c645,
    0x0b95c1e4, 0x0c57c9c4, 0x0d1adf5b, 0x0ddf0420,
    0x0ea4398b, 0x0f6a8118, 0x1031dc43, 0x10fa4c8c,
    0x11c3d374, 0x128e727e, 0x135a2b2f, 0x1426ff10,
    0x14f4efa9, 0x15c3fe87, 0x16942d37, 0x17657d4a,
    0x1837f052, 0x190b87e2, 0x19e04593, 0x1ab62afd,
    0x1b8d39ba, 0x1c657368, 0x1d3ed9a7, 0x1e196e19,
    0x1ef53261, 0x1fd22825, 0x20b05110, 0x218faecb,
    0x22704303, 0x23520f69, 0x243515ae, 0x25195787,
    0x25fed6aa, 0x26e594d0, 0x27cd93b5, 0x28b6d516,
    0x29a15ab5, 0x2a8d2653, 0x2b7a39b6, 0x2c6896a5,
    0x2d583eea, 0x2e493453, 0x2f3b78ad, 0x302f0dcc,
    0x3123f582, 0x321a31a6, 0x3311c413, 0x340aaea2,
    0x3504f334, 0x360093a8, 0x36fd91e3, 0x37fbefcb,
    0x38fbaf47, 0x39fcd245, 0x3aff5ab2, 0x3c034a7f,
    0x3d08a39f, 0x3e0f680a, 0x3f1799b6, 0x40213aa2,
    0x412c4cca, 0x4238d231, 0x4346ccda, 0x44563ecc,
    0x45672a11, 0x467990b6, 0x478d74c9, 0x48a2d85d,
    0x49b9bd86, 0x4ad2265e, 0x4bec14ff, 0x4d078b86,
    0x4e248c15, 0x4f4318cf, 0x506333db, 0x5184df62,
    0x52a81d92, 0x53ccf09a, 0x54f35aac, 0x561b5dff,
    0x5744fccb, 0x5870394c, 0x599d15c2, 0x5acb946f,
    0x5bfbb798, 0x5d2d8185, 0x5e60f482, 0x5f9612df,
    0x60ccdeec, 0x62055b00, 0x633f8973, 0x647b6ca0,
    0x65b906e7, 0x66f85aab, 0x68396a50, 0x697c3840,
    0x6ac0c6e8, 0x6c0718b6, 0x6d4f301f, 0x6e990f98,
    0x6fe4b99c, 0x713230a8, 0x7281773c, 0x73d28fde,
    0x75257d15, 0x767a416c, 0x77d0df73, 0x792959bb,
    0x7a83b2db, 0x7bdfed6d, 0x7d3e0c0d, 0x7e9e115c,
    0x80000000, 0x8163daa0
};

int32_t fixed_exp2 (int32_t x)
{
    int32_t f1, f2, dx, a, b, approx, idx, i, f;

    /* extract integer portion; 2**i is realized as a shift at the end */
    i = (x >> 26);
    /* extract fraction f so we can compute 2^f, 0 <= f < 1 */
    f = x & 0x3ffffff;
    /* index table of exp2 values using 7 most significant bits of fraction */
    idx = (uint32_t)f >> (26 - 7);
    /* difference between argument and next smaller sampling point */
    dx = f - (idx << (26 - 7));
    /* fit parabola through closest 3 sampling points; find coefficients a,b */
    f1 = (expTab[idx+1] - expTab[idx]);
    f2 = (expTab[idx+2] - expTab[idx]);
    a = f2 - (f1 << 1);
    b = (f1 << 1) - a;
    /* find function value offset for argument x by computing ((a*dx+b)*dx) */
    approx = a;
    approx = (int32_t)((((int64_t)approx)*dx) >> (26 - 7)) + b;
    approx = (int32_t)((((int64_t)approx)*dx) >> (26 - 7 + 1));
    /* combine integer and fractional parts of result, round result */
    approx = (((expTab[idx] + (uint32_t)approx + (uint32_t)(1.0*(1LL << 31)) + 22U) >> (30 - 26 - i)) + 1) >> 1;
    /* flush underflow to 0 */
    if (i < -27) approx = 0;
    return approx;
}
```

Comment: I was just wondering if you have applied similar concept to fixed-point log2 function (results in s15.16 format).

Comment: @Ali: I have in the past (about 15 years ago, before floating-point units on ARM processors were common).

Comment: @Ali You could always ask a question, that is what this site is for :-)

Comment: Sometimes I'm amazed by how people come so close to figuring out polynomial LUTs but stop short. Instead of using a LUT of naive values and then deriving a quadratic polynomial from 3 such consecutive values, you could have a LUT of precomputed polynomial coefficients, so the core approximation would just be computing the index then doing 2 multiplications and 2 additions. Just decide what the range of each LUT entry represents, then fit a polynomial in that range, and store the coefficients in it. I've been using that technique for years, sometimes even with quintic tables, it's great.

Comment: @MichelRouzic While I am aware of this technique, I have not actually used it. It would be useful to StackOverflow users to see a worked example, so I encourage writing this up as a proper answer.

Comment: You've heard of it before? I wasn't able to find any literature on the topic and I would like to find some as I'm thinking of making a video on the topic. Anyway while I've made exp2 and log2 fixed point implementations (see https://github.com/Photosounder/rouziclib/blob/master/rouziclib/fixedpoint/fp.c#L192) I made them before I figured out polynomial LUTs. I did use that approach to approximate the reciprocal function in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765597/1675589.

Comment: If you look for "piecewise polynomial approximation", you should be able to find relevant literature. Implementations I have seen didn't use anything above cubic polynomials (splines). I reverse-engineered one based on linear approximation for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614611/floating-point-reciprocal-approximation-using-softfloat-library). The trade-off with on-the-fly coefficient computation as I am showing here would appear to be an increase in total table storage, which in *my* experience with FP-less embedded  systems (~200 MHz ARM32) is not so attractive.

Comment: Thanks. I only target modern computers, and the rule that I follow is if I don't get the necessary precision with a given polynomial degree with a table of 3 kB or less (to avoid overcrowding the ~32 kB L1 cache) I use the next degree so that I don't increase the size of the table and get more precision, so increased size isn't a concern for me. But for first degree polynomials the advantages of using polynomial coefficients rather than interpolating a naive table are indeed doubtful.

Comment: Dear njuffa, why using f in range[-0.5 0.5] but not in the range[0,1] like your answer in log2 fixed point?

Comment: @RJ. Lo Using [-0.5,0.5] as the primary approximation interval for a minimax polynomial approximation to exp2(x)-1 is numerically advantageous compared to the use of [0,1]. Choosing [0,1] can be OK for low-accuracy approximations and slightly simplifies the code, but here we have a high-accuracy approximation.