# derive exponential function using log() in C

Tags: c, logarithm, exp, natural-logarithm

I am trying to derive exponential function using logarithms. I know from below equation
log(22026.4657948067), is 10
and
exp(10) is 22026.4657948067

I would like to understand the basic math behind exp() and log(). At the moment, I have log() in C and I would like to know the conversion logic so that I can calculate exponential() from log().
Thank you

Comment: `the basic math behind exp() and log()` is e^x and the natural logarithm of x. What do you actually want to know?

Comment: exp and log are inverse functions.  I don't know of a good way of implementing one in terms of the other.  Since they're inverses, you could use a general-purpose inversion metafunction, such as [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), but it wouldn't be a very efficient way of doing it.  I believe that both of them are conventionally, and reasonably straightforwardly, calculated using [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansions.

Comment: But then , I should know pow() and I don't have power function implementation in fixed point C. You can suggest please other option - how to go about it . Thanks

Comment: I have successfully computed both of these using what I learned in the "Computation" sections of the Wikipedia articles on  the [Logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Power_series) and [Exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Computation), respectively.  It's not easy at first — there are some significant hurdles to overcome, if you want your functions to work well, and be accurate, over their entire input range — but it's an interesting and instructive challenge.

Comment: can you please share a little easy and numeric way of doing, I have fixed point log() available.

Comment: The `log()` function you have isn't going to help you.  As I suggested earlier, start with [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Computation) (or maybe [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function)).  But, no, there is not a "little, easy" way of doing this: it's real work.

Comment: The question seems to be a potential duplicate of various existing questions, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64941736/efficient-implementation-of-fixed-point-power-pow-function-with-argument-const/64978770#64978770), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657468/fast-fixed-point-pow-log-exp-and-sqrt), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736820/fixed-point-approximation-of-2x-with-input-range-of-s5-26/53740645#53740645)

Comment: @Coder I am not a downvoter, nor do I speak for the downvoters. Please note that before posting a question, askers on this site are expected to search for relevant *existing* questions whose answers may already provide the desired information. The purpose of this is to avoid redundant questions. In my previous comment, I linked three potential duplicate questions that appear relevant to the question asked here. Is the information you see there sufficient for your use case? If not, please clarify your question to specify how the information you seek differs from that found in existing contents.

Comment: @Coder I can't explain the downvotes, either, but I can say that I'm perplexed.  You've asked for help writing a fixed-point `exp()`, and you're received lots of hints and pointers.  I'm not sure what you're still looking for, or why you posted [that follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70964009).  If you're looking for someone to actually write the function for you, you're in the wrong place: that's not what Stack Overflow is for, and it looks like no one here is going to do that for you.

Comment: @SteveSummit, Understood , I am bit non regular and new to stackoverflow so i am unaware of stuff. Many  thanks for all the help and suggestion. I have to  work my self and improve. May be should delete the followup question :-)

Comment: It appears that what you ask is more a mathematical question than a programming one, an illustration of a theoretical idea. The "express way" to define the "natural" logarithm and its inverse exponential, and what is "natural" about them, is to define `ln(x)=int(1 .. x, t => 1/t)`, prove its elementary properties and define the exponential as its inverse. All this is horribly inefficient from a numerical point-of-view, but might be used as a test for a faster implementation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, Exactly the inverse derivation is what I am looking from numeric calculation. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There's no "conversion logic". They're both transcendental functions and there's no nice way to implement one in terms of the other. Since they're inverses, you could use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or some other root-finding method to find the zero of `log(x) - a`, and call that value `exp(a)`, but that would be both less accurate and vastly less efficient than using the builtin implementation.

If you're asking how those functions are usually implemented in mathematical libraries, a common approach is range reduction followed by polynomial approximation. For instance, any positive number can be reduced into the range `[1,2)` by multiplying or dividing it by two zero or more times; and `log(x * 2) == log(x) + log(2)`, so all we need is a high-precision constant for `log(2)`, to be added or subtracted from the final result the appropriate number of times. Then we can use a Taylor series for the function `log(1+x)` over `[0,1)`; you can get high accuracy without too many terms because of the limited domain. Alternatively, lookup tables and linear interpolation could be used on platforms where multiplication is particularly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The logarithms returns the exponent to which a base must be raised to yield a given number.

So if we have x=9, then (base 3) log(9) = 2 because 3^2 = 9.

In C the log() function uses base e where e is the Euler's number (2.71828).

So in your case what's happening is basically:
log(22026.4657948067) = 10 and then e^10 = 22026.4657948067

Comment: But basically power(base,exp) are the  two entities which should be  known , but the problem is missing power function . Any clue how to implement for all base and exponent? Unfortunately, you answer is not helpful for me .

Comment: So you are saying that you would like to implement a way to calculate the power and the logarithm of a number given the base?

Comment: I am of the opinion power() can do exponent () using logarithm. Since I don't have fixed point power() either I am looking other options as well.