# How to derive power function for real number base and exponent in C

Tags: c, point, fixed, pow

I am trying to implement fixed point C code for power function i.e. without using math.h library

For example
% **base = linspace(-10,10,4)**
% **exp = linspace(-5,5,4)**

I want to implement fixed point power() in C. Below is the pseudo code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void main()
{
  int i,j;
  double base[4] = [-10,-3.33333333333333,3.33333333333333,10];
  double exp[4] = [-5,-1.66666666666667,1.66666666666667,5];
  for (i =0; i < 4;i++)
  {
     for(j = 0;j < 4;j++)
     {
         output(i,j) =  power(base[i],exp[j]);
     }
  }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Implementing `pow(a, b)` using logarithms is easy: it's basically `exp(log(a) * b)`.  But of course that means you need `exp()`, as in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958051/derive-exponential-function-using-log-in-c).

Comment: You can't assign to a function call in C. Is `output` supposed to be an array?

Comment: `exp` is an array, not a function. So it should be `exp[j]`

Comment: Are you a Fortran programmer by any chance?

Comment: @Barmar Looks like Matlab

Comment: He did say it was pseudocode.

Comment: @SteveSummit, yes,I need exp() as well.

Comment: What do you mean by *fixed point power*? How do you define `(-10)^(-5)` ?

Comment: you define -10 and -5 as Q5.27 and Q4.28  . Please have a look , for -5 value in a 32 bit DSP where 32 is word size contains integer and fractional bits. I am not allowed to stored the data in double or float . -5 real world value will be  -1342177280 and with respect to Q4.28 format , one can do -1342177280 * 2 ^ -28 to get  back -5. I hope it is clear. Similarly I can do for  -10

Comment: The calculated value for power(-10,-5) is -0.0000100000000000